# I'm getting empty results attached in SMTP sampler

Tags: jmeter

JMeter results I'm getting through different listener's,I want the results to come in mail
I tried it through smtp sampler
But, I'm getting mails without the results[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not see any sign of attaching a file to the email in your [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler), you should add the .jtl results file as attachment:

   [image: JMeter Email Attachment]
2. You may also need to amend one JMeter Property as by default JMeter doesn't store results as soon as samplers are finished, it flushes them to file in chunks

   ```
   # AutoFlush on each line written in XML or CSV output
   # Setting this to true will result in less test results data loss in case of Crash
   # but with impact on performances, particularly for intensive tests (low or no pauses)
   # Since JMeter 2.10, this is false by default
   #jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
   ```

   So add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

   and restart JMeter to pick the property up. Or alternatively you can set the property via -J command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on tuning JMeter using properties.

Comment: thank you i saw that after posting the screenshot,but even after setting the auto flash to true i'm getting my previous results only